# How to observe (KVO) count change in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, key-value-observing

I have an array with nested `NSMutableArrays.`

I would like to be notified when ever one of the nested arrays has a change in number of objects.

I have read several methods but do not understand how this is done.

(i.e. `insertObject:atIndex:`)

Comment: Have you read this: http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/ ?

Comment: you cant observe count on nsarray.

Comment: Okay.  I didn't know.  I was just making sure you read that and it wasn't something simple.

Comment: @AvnerBarr: So what is your question exactly? You *know* that you can't observe the count of an NSArray, but you are asking *how* to observe a count change in an array?

Comment: There should be a way using nsproxy or overriding some methods using kvc